# Building a service for a Drupal site to duplicate a node to another Drupal site in a multi-site setup

Tags: api, drupal-6, service, push

I'm trying to set up one of my Drupal sites to push a node to another Drupal site in a multi-site configuration. It looks like I need to do this with services somehow, but I can't find any tutorials out there and I need at least to be pointed in the right direction.
What I believe I need is set up Services on the receiving site to accept a call from the sending site which will be sending the node object via Json or serialized PHP using a Key that was set up on the receiving site. Can anyone show me an example of this working or give me some insight?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you checked out the [deploy](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) module on d.o (drupal.org)? It's a great tool to push changes (also nodes) from one installation to another. It uses the services module for the communication.
I have not tested it with a multisite installation, but I guess it should work if at least the domain names are different for each site.

Regards

Mike